# How to get the full json response in android?

Tags: android, json

I am getting half json response from url and print in logcat. The response contains large data so how can i get the full json response.

Comment: Although we'd love to guess at the problem, it would be very helpful to see what code you are using to issue web requests and parse your JSON responses.

Comment: Check this answer to increase logcat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618977/android-studio-maximum-number-of-lines-logcat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Set max length of logcat messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888654/android-set-max-length-of-logcat-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [library](https://github.com/tianzhijiexian/Android-Best-Practices) may help you to solve the problem ，but it's document is written by Chinese . I have translated the main part for you :

1. You need to init the lib in your onCreate method like this:          **L.init()**;
2. And then you can use it to print your json info like this:
   **L.json(youJsonObj.toString());**

[The logcat will show like this:](https://github.com/tianzhijiexian/Android-Best-Practices/blob/master/2015.8/log/json.png?raw=true)

Comment: @Smittey  Thanks for advice.