# Truncated JSON in android

Tags: java, android, json

With  help from some guys on this site i was able to get the correct JSON from WebApi. However while trying to receive JSON on my client via OkHTTP the JSON array is truncated i.e part of it is removed.I don't understand if it's OKHTTP that is doing that. Here's my JSON :

```
[{"AccountType":"15516321","CustomerName":"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"1100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"150010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"}]},{"AccountType":"25526322","CustomerName":"2MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"2100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"150010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"}]},{"AccountType":"35536323","CustomerName":"3MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"3100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"150010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:22:17"}]}]
```

however once i recieve this JSON array via my client code i.e.:

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                    try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {

                        if (!response.isSuccessful())

                            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();

                        for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {

                            Log.d("Results", responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));

                        }


                        //Log.d("Results", responseBody.string());       
                        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                        JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(responseBody.string());
                        Log.d("JsonObject", element.toString());

    //etc....code
                    }
                }
```

I get this JSON as result that show it has been truncated somewhere in the middle:

```
12-15 13:33:39.092: D/JsonObject(7935): [{"AccountType":"15516321","CustomerName":"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"1100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"150010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 13:33:40"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTrans
```

Please what could be making this to happen?

I Just want to get the JSON data from API and Traverse them 
Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated

Comment: It's not truncated, it's just a ```LogCat``` limitation. You have a max number of chars that can be printed out in ```LogCat```. Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618977/android-studio-maximum-number-of-lines-logcat

Comment: Its just logcats character limit, test your api call in a rest client like postman and check the result is what you expect

Comment: Ok  @danypata/@Michael thats abit reassuring.However how can i convert the JSON to an ArrayList? Any decent suggestions :)

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array

Comment: thxs @Michael for the heads up

Comment: Next time, try to compare the length of both JSON or save it in a file ;)